# problemas al conectar Visual Studio Code SSH con mi servidor

Tags: ssh, visual

buenas noches srs Foristas!

soy nuevo en estas lidias y pues me encuentro vuelto un rollo con el siguiente error, me sale cuando intento conectarme VISUAL STUDIO CODE via SSH con mi servidor... me gustaria saber que significa y como podre solucuonarlo

```
[22:31:05.209] > C:\\Users\\carri/.ssh/config line 5: garbage at end of line; "ssh\\magen_server"
> .
> 
[22:31:05.217] > El proceso ha intentado escribir en una canalización que no existe.
> 
[22:31:05.650] "install" terminal command done
[22:31:05.650] Install terminal quit with output: El proceso ha intentado escribir en una canalización que no existe.
[22:31:05.650] Received install output: El proceso ha intentado escribir en una canalización que no existe.
[22:31:05.651] Stopped parsing output early. Remaining text: El proceso ha intentado escribir en una canalización que no existe.
[22:31:05.651] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[22:31:05.651] Resolver error: 
[22:31:05.654] ------
```

agradezco de antemano a los expertos que me puedan guiar!

saludos y gracias!

JCC

Comment: Esta publicación no se ajusta a Cómo preguntar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, recomiendo hagas el recorrido: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

me salia el mismo error al intentar conectar con mi servidor linux por ssh, mi error estaba en la sintaxis del archivo de configuracion ssh, en tu terminal te esta diciendo en que linea del archivo de configuracion tienes el error "line 5: garbage", espero haber podido ayudar

Comment: Hola, aunque es una respuesta, date cuenta que se trata de una respuesta vaga y con pocas aclaraciones, considera añadir una explicación aclarando cuál es el error y por qué sucedió.